# react-select: default autocomplete option

Tags: react-select

I'm using react-select for an autocomplete, and wanna suggest users a "default" option, if there're no matches to what they've typed, among available options. E.g. available options are "Orange", "Banana" and "Other", where "Other" is a valid option as well, and whenever a user types smth which doesn't match to neither "Orange" nor "Banana" I wanna have the "Other" option dropping down, so they can click it and select it. How can I do it with react-select?